# Ubuntu Software Center Disappears

Tags: software-center

I've installed Ubuntu on my laptop (Dell Latitude) - works great - initially Software centre worked great.... I did updates..

Now Software Center when run comes up and before it has a chance to put images up - it disappears - repeating gives same result. I've tried reboot, sudo apt-get remove software-center (and reinstall same name) - same result.

Ideas anyone??

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Check error logs for detailed information

Comment: 16.04 LTSAs for logs - not sure where to look as I'm not a whizz at Linux.